# Entity Framework Generated Column Names

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a `Job` Entity which has 2 collections of the same type

```
    public virtual ICollection<Device> ExistingDevices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> NewDevices { get; set; }
```

On the Device Entity, it refers back to the `Job`

```
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

On the surface, this works just fine, however on the database, if you look at a device you see this

```
//Devices Table in Db

|JobId |  Job_Id | Job_Id1 |
```

My setup includes Entity configuration objects for using fluent API, however I have not worked out how to fix this. The first JobId is fine, it is a perfect description of the data. The second two refer to the `ExistingDevices` and `NewDevices` lists they belong to. The headers are not at all descriptive.

Is it possible to rename these columns to something more appropriate?

//Edit

It has the FK `JobId` but also if the device is in the ExistingDevices list, the JobId also gets put into `Job_Id` and `Job_Id1` is null. If the device belongs to the NewDevices list, the `Job_Id` is null and the `Job_Id1` has the JobId in it.

Naming the Job_id to ExistingDevices and Job_Id1 to NewDevices would make it much clearer in Db.

**Update**

Having slept on it, I decided it was a design fault.

I changed the `Device` Model to have

```
public bool NewDevice { get; set; }
```

and changed the `Job` Model by removing the 2 existing ICollections and adding

```
public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
```

Rather than having two device collections, I now have one, with a properly descriptive FK. In the database a 1 or 0 will indicate new or existing device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two one to many relationship, the database will have two foreign key columns on the dependent entity (`Device`). `JobId` might represent `ExistingDevices` and `JobId1` might represent `NewDevices`.

To be clear you should define two navigation properties as follow.

```
public int? ExistingJobId { get; set; }
public virtual Job ExistingJob { get; set; } 
public int? NewJobId { get; set; }
public virtual Job NewJob { get; set; }
```

Then can configure the relationship using [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.ExistingJob)
        .WithMany(x => x.ExistingDevices)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ExistingJobId);
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.NewJob)
        .WithMany(x => x.NewDevices)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.NewJobId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Note, one foreign key is defined without cascading delete (`false`) because [multiple cascading delete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is not allowed.

**update**: the required existing job and new job have been changed into optional.

Comment: The dependent is the Device. When a job is created it can have a list of 'ExistingDevices' and/or 'NewDevices' but they are optional. The `Device` table has the 3 references to JobId as described, one for the FK to the Job record the other two relate to which list they belong. I dont want three job navigation properies on the device as it should only relate to 1 job.

Comment: @James, I misstyped the dependent, it should be the device, in your question you have two columns of `JobId`, is it possible or you misstyped it?

Comment: @James, and it is impossible if you have to multiplicity on the principal and only relate to 1 job, unless you use `Table Per Hierarchy mapping which required to introduce inheritance

Comment: I've tried to elaborate in my original question. Hope it makes more sense. You were correct about my column name typo.

Comment: @James, each relationship will represent a FK in the database, the first multiplicity is found by convention in the principal `ExistingDevices` and it will search the reference on the dependent to decide whether the FK is required/optional, the second multiplicity is found on the principal `NewDevices` but EF can't find in the dependent, EF'll still create the FK and it will become optional, I think the second `Job_Id` and third `Job_Id1` are the actual foreign keys because the dependent navigation properties doesn't fit the [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: I understand what you mean, I removed the first `JobId` which leaves the other 2. I Created the navigation properties and FKs as suggested. I now have `ExistingJobId` and `NewJobId` columns as well as the `Job_Id` and `Job_Id1`. The new columns remain null and Job_Id ones are populated on data import. - Thank for looking at it and you were right about breach of convention. Thinking i've looked too long so will look at it tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: @James, and one more info, you can rename the FK in the database two ways, first you rename the navigation property in the class `public int ExistingJobId {get;set;}` then configure it with `.HasForeignKey(x => x.ExistingJobId)`, second you rename it by using `.Map(x => x.MapKey("Existing_Job_Id"))`, but the second option will simply create two columns, the normal `ExistingJobId` column and the FK `Existing_Job_Id` column, the second option is used if you don't have the FK property value the class `public int ExistingJobId {get;set;}`, hopefully it helps..